# Why does C use multiple namespaces?

Tags: c, namespaces

To elaborate further why do structs use a different namespace to unions,variables,ect. Wouldn't it be more convenient to just have one namespace?

Is there a reason C is designed this way?

Comment: It would indeed be more convenient... and C++ essentially reached the same effect with a subtle variation of this dual namespace historic choice.

Comment: With a single namespace, you couldn’t use the same identifier as a member name and regular variable name - e.g., you couldn’t write `thing.id = id;`.  For me, that would count as “less” convenient.